# error can not show in my laravel vue js project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I can't show my error in my laravel vue js project.

My Controller

```
return response()->json(['error'=>'You Already Review This Product'], 422);
```

My Browser response successfully shows the error. The image in the link.
https://i.postimg.cc/yYB8mXmB/error.png

My Vue Component Script

```
reviewPost(){
                this.$Progress.start();
                this.review.post('/api/product/review')
                .then(response=>{
                    Fire.$emit('getReview'+this.$route.params.slug);
                    this.review.reset();
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: response.data,
                    });
                    this.$Progress.finish();
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Here i want to show my error',
                    });
                    this.$Progress.fail();
                });
            },
```

Console.log(error) showing this.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (app.js:702)
    at settle (app.js:977)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:169)
```

Now How I Fix This Problem.

Comment: See this link: [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422). It sounds like your server is unable to process the request for some reason.  Possibly a bug in the server code, or the request content is not what the server is expecting.

Comment: 404 also not working. Now Do you have any idea to solve this problem

Comment: You may know that 404 is resource not found, as in possibly the API endpoint in your post URL is wrong.  At this point I recommend using an API testing app like Postman or Insomnia to send requests to the API and go from there.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. I can send any custom data to my controller. Now I want to send an error message with an error status code, That code could be 404,422,500, etc & I will write this code manually so that the browser cache it is an error. I want to send an error message with an error status that I catch the error and show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your problem now.  I have had to deal with similar processing myself.

Since it looks like the error returned has the JSON format:

```
{
    "error": "You Already Review This Product"
}
```

you can add logic similar to this to your 'catch(error)':

```
.catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
        if (error.response) {
                if (error.response.status == 422) {
                        let errorMessage = error.response.data.error;
                        Toast.fire({
                                icon: 'error',
                                title: errorMessage,
                        });

                        this.$Progress.fail();
                }
                else {
                        console.error("Response contains error code " + error.response.status);
                }
        }
        else if (error.request) {
                console.error("No response received so logging request");
                console.error(error.request);
        }
        else {
                console.error("Problem with request: " + error.message);
        }
});
```

BTW, I use Axios for calling REST APIs, and I'm not sure if other ways of calling REST APIs may use a different error structure.  As you probably know, you can see the error object structure in the console log.

Comment: When I console.log(error); it show me Error: Request failed with status code 422 but when I console.log(error.response); It Show me full information and this is I need. Now I can use the error information title: error.response.data.error,. Thanks